# Adding folders to java classpath at runtime

Tags: java, classloader

I want to use **class.forName** to load a class (included in a jar file) from a different project. I found below piece of code in stackoverflow. It works fine if I know the name of Jar file.

```
File f = new File("D:/workspace/secondproject/lib/temp.jar");
            URI u = f.toURI();
            URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            Class<URLClassLoader> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
            Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
            method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[]{u.toURL()});
            try {
              Class.forName ("pk1.foo");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
               System.out.println ("Failed.");
            }
```

However, the code does not work when I pass the address of folder contains the jar file and not the address of jar file. In the above example **D:/workspace/secondproject/lib**.

I have no idea why it does not work. I expect when I pass a folder it searches all files in this directory. Please let me know what I did wrong and how can I pass a folder to classPath at runtime.

Comment: Why wont you scan folder to a *.jar files and open it in loop?

Comment: My project uses many different Java projects and I think it is faster if I only pass project address instead of extracting all jar files and then use them. Note that jar files can be in different folders in the different projects and I should consider all files in the project which can be time consuming.

Comment: As I understand, you can pass absolute paths to you programm in command line. It looks like:  program --libs=PATH_1,PATH_2. You can parse arguments your main() method and get array of string with paths.

Comment: Why aren't the projects linked as dependencies? This way, with the correct build process, they will be included within your jars classpath and loaded automatically...and the class resolution will be done at compile time...

Comment: Or specify the jars as -cp elements on the command line...

Comment: Also, there is a dangerous assumption that the underlying class loader is a URLClassloader, which may not always be true

Comment: If I add projects as dependencies, then it works. But, my project is a plugin that does not know about projects until runtime, and I do not want to add and remove projects during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: it doesn't work that way.

You have to traverse the files in the folder and add them.